# Bugzilla 5.0 REST API Authentication in headers

Tags: bugzilla

Using the Bugzilla 5.0 REST API, how do I send the API key in a header?

The following works with a 200 response and creates a bug:

```
curl -Ski -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"
-H "Accept: application/json"
--data "@$HOME/bug_attrs.json"
"https://fmd-bugzil-01tst.vrt.sourcefire.com/rest/bug?Bugzilla_api_key=ibMexQ7suwgyiYNskgxgBDqrXGLV5Jkogj1KSYL0"
```

But sending it in the header returns a 401:

```
curl -Ski -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json"
-H "Accept: application/json"
-H "X-BUGZILLA-API-KEY: ibMexQ7suwgyiYNskgxgBDqrXGLV5Jkogj1KSYL0"
--data "@$HOME/bug_attrs.json"
"https://fmd-bugzil-01tst.vrt.sourcefire.com/rest/bug"
```

How do I send the API Key in the headers instead of the Query string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are using stable version of Bugzilla, version 5.0.4, according to the documentation for [Rest API 5.0.4](https://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/5.0/api/core/v1/general.html#authentication), it does not support `X-BUGZILLA-API-KEY` header for authentication.

However, latest [version 5.1.2](https://bugzilla.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/core/v1/general.html#authentication) has support for allowing api key in the header.

> Alternatively, authentication credentials can be provided via one of
>   the following headers:
>
> X-BUGZILLA-LOGIN
>
> X-BUGZILLA-PASSWORD
>
> X-BUGZILLA-API-KEY
>
> X-BUGZILLA-TOKEN
>
> Credentials passed as part of the query string take
>   precedence over the header credentials.